# Using Unity assets bought in AssetStore.Unity3D.com in Non-Unity projects

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

Does anybody know am I allowed to use Unity assets bought by me in AssetStore.Unity3D.com in Non-Unity projects? I mean to use it in Native-Java development, Native-iOS dev, using it with LibGDX Engine and other engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unity Asset Store TOS](http://unity3d.com/legal/as_terms) (Terms of Service):

> [..]
>
> 2. END-USER'S RIGHTS AND OBLIGATIONS
>
> 2.1
>
> END-USER may use the licensed Assets only for their intended purpose.
>
> 2.2
>
> Licensor grants to the END-USER a non-exclusive, worldwide, and
>   perpetual license to the Asset to integrate Assets **only as
>   incorporated and embedded components of electronic games and
>   interactive media and distribute such electronic game and interactive
>   media**. Except for game services software development kits (“Services
>   SDKs”), END-USERS may modify Assets. END-USER may otherwise not
>   reproduce, distribute, sublicense, rent, lease or lend the Assets. It
>   is emphasized that the **END-USERS shall not be entitled to distribute
>   or transfer in any way** (including, without, limitation by way of
>   sublicense) the Assets in any other way than as integrated components
>   of electronic games and interactive media. Without limitation of the
>   foregoing it is emphasized that END-USER shall not be entitled to
>   share the costs related to purchasing an Asset and then let any third
>   party that has contributed to such purchase use such Asset (forum
>   pooling).
>
> [...]

Therefore I ASSUME that you should ask the owner/developer. Each license could be different so I recommend you to research each of them.

-----> UPDATE <------

So according to the TOS you can do whatever you want. The Asset Store is clearly separated from Unity Engine and Unity gets a cut from the purchase. However, They prefer you use them in Unity, but nowhere it the EULA is that mentioned at all.

Comment: So I'm allowed to use my purchases from UnityAssetStore in non-unity games (like Cocos2dx, LibGDX, Marmalade), right?

Comment: Yes, but regardless you should talk to the owner just to be sure.

Comment: thanks! I will talk with owners of assets to be sure that I'm allowed to use it in other Game Engines.

Comment: by the way, do you happen to know: has Unity some private messaging system at the AssetStore?

Comment: What do you mean with "private messaging system"?

Comment: I mean that I don't know how to connect with author of the Asset. I try to connect via twitter but it looks like it's not the best way for contacting with author :)

Comment: You can use the support for the asset/plugin and ask there.